# Error data and dividing on 0

Tags: sql, case, zero, divide

Need help to clear the error:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
    CASE WHEN (proj.UserText1 IS NULL OR proj.UserText1 = '') 
         THEN 0.00 
         ELSE
         CASE 
            WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 
            THEN (((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) * (proj.UserText1 / 100.0) 
                ELSE ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * (proj.UserText1 / 100.0) 
            END 
    END AS [Accrued Commission],

    CASE WHEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0) OR (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN 100.00 
         ELSE 
             CASE WHEN (Paid.Paid IS NULL OR Paid.Paid = 0) OR (sopHdr.DOCAMNT = 0 OR sopHdr.DOCAMNT IS NULL) THEN 0.00 
                  ELSE (Paid.Paid / sopHdr.DOCAMNT) * 100 
    END END AS [Paid %],

    CASE WHEN sopHdr.DOCAMNT < 0 THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT) 
         WHEN (sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 AND sopHdr.DOCAMNT > 0) THEN (sopHdr.DOCAMNT * - 1) 
    ELSE CASE WHEN Paid.Paid IS NULL THEN 0.00 
              ELSE Paid.Paid 
    END END AS [Amount Received],

    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 
         THEN (inv.TaxTotal * - 1) 
         ELSE inv.TaxTotal 
    END AS [Tax Amount],

    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN CAST(CAST(((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) AS DECIMAL(13,6)) as float)
         ELSE CAST(CAST((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal)AS DECIMAL(13,6)) as float)
    END AS [Gross Profit],

    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (inv.CostTotal * - 1) 
         ELSE inv.CostTotal 
    END AS [Ext Cost],

    CASE WHEN (proj.UserText1 IS NULL OR proj.UserText1 = '') THEN CAST('0.00' as varchar) 
         ELSE CAST(proj.UserText1 as varchar)
    END AS [Commission %],


    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN CAST(CAST(((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) * - 1) AS DECIMAL(13,6)) as float)
         ELSE CAST(CAST((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) AS DECIMAL(13,6)) as float)
    END AS [Net Sales],
```

And the error:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 16 
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

```
Case#9
        CASE WHEN (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL IS NULL OR sopHdr.SUBTOTAL = 0) THEN 0.00 
                ELSE 
                    CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) /(sopHdr.SUBTOTAL) - (inv.TaxTotal)) * - 100
                    ELSE (((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL) - (inv.TaxTotal)) * 100)
                    END 
        END AS [Sale Gross Profit %],
```

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Try changing `(Paid.Paid IS NULL OR Paid.Paid = 0) OR (sopHdr.DOCAMNT = 0 OR sopHdr.DOCAMNT IS NULL)` to `((Paid.Paid IS NULL) OR (Paid.Paid = 0)) OR ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT = 0) OR (sopHdr.DOCAMNT IS NULL))`. There might me an issue of precedence. Also, which DBMS are you using, Oracle?

Comment: Thanks. I am using SQL

Comment: I am getting still the same message, but I think each of the case needs to be  converted.

Comment: Looks like this particular case is the issue: CASE WHEN (proj.UserText1 IS NULL OR
                      proj.UserText1 = '') THEN 0.00 ELSE CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN (((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * - 1) * (proj.UserText1 / 100.0) 
                      ELSE ((sopHdr.DOCAMNT - inv.TaxTotal) - inv.CostTotal) * (proj.UserText1 / 100.0) 
       END END AS [Accrued Commission],

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get `Divide by zero` error when you are dividing by constants, only table fields or expressions containing ones.
As sql is declarative language, even if you write something like this:

```
select a/b
from table
where b <> 0
```

your database engine might decide that it is easier to calculate this for each record and filter out later, which obviously will give you this error.
Assuming yoy're using sql server, I used to write this way:

```
select a/NULLIF(b, 0)
from table
where b <> 0
```

`NULLIF()` will convert zeros to nulls and instead of errors, you will get `null`, (of course in the example above there will be no rows with nulls)

Comment: Yes, it works. CASE WHEN (sopHdr.SUBTOTAL IS NULL OR sopHdr.SUBTOTAL = 0) THEN 0.00 
       ELSE 
        CASE WHEN sopHdr.SOPTYPE = 4 THEN ((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / NULLIF((NULLIF(sopHdr.SUBTOTAL,0) - NULLIF(inv.TaxTotal,0)),0)) * - 100
          ELSE (((sopHdr.SUBTOTAL - inv.TaxTotal - inv.CostTotal) / NULLIF((NULLIF(sopHdr.SUBTOTAL,0) - NULLIF(inv.TaxTotal,0)),0)) * 100)
        END 
     END AS [Sale Gross Profit %],